# <div> with image has a bigger height than expected

Tags: html, css, image, layout

Here is an HTML code to reproduce the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
            <img src="logo.gif" width="100" height="40" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When it is rendered in a desktop browser, the height of the only `<div>` becomes 45 pixels but not 40 as I expect (tested this in IE11 and Opera Next v20). logo.gif is 100x40, and the situation remains the same even if I apply zero border through CSS to the `<img>` tag (border, border-width, etc).

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: One observation from my side. If we display a border around the image (say with the `style="border: 3px solid black;"` attribute), we can see that there is a 4-pixel padding between the image bottom and the div bottom edge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it is not a bug as it is rendered the same way in all major browsers. The problem is fixed if we set just the `display:block` style. Without this, the image is rendered as an inline element, and its bottom border is aligned to the so called text baseline.

Let's change our code to demonstrate this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color: #FFFF99;">
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto; background-color: #00CCFF;">
<img src="logo.gif" width="100" height="40" style="border: 3px solid black;" />
Some text yyy qqq
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is the following:

[image]

As you can see, the extra space is needed to render the text without clipping!

---

I found a confirmation of that in the well-known book by Eric Meyer [CSS: The Definitive Guide](http://meyerweb.com/eric/books/css-tdg/) - in the section dedicated to alignment, when it describes the `{vertical-align: baseline}` attribute for the `<img>` tag. Here is the corresponding excerpt:

> This alignment rule is important because it causes some web browsers always to put a replaced element's bottom edge on the baseline, even if there is no other text in the line. For example, let's say you have an image in a table cell all by itself. The image may actually be on a baseline, but in some browsers, the space below the baseline causes a gap to appear beneath the image. Other browsers will "shrink-wrap" the image with the table cell and no gap will appear. The gap behavior is correct, according to the CSS Working Group, despite its lack of appeal to most authors.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue in FireFox and IE and Chrome.

You can fix this with a hack and add a `Height:40px;` to your div (I had to use an image to with the same width/height as your logo so don't be surprised that I have a different picture)

```
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;border:solid;height:40px;">
    <img src="http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Video/16/96/5f/mzi.rxlappss.100x100-75.jpg" width="100" height="40" />
</div>
```

Or, add some CSS to your image tag and keep the original code as is (will affect all images which may not be desirable)

```
img {padding:none;margin:none;display:block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6wrA/

Or, you can do this for only certain images with http://jsfiddle.net/h6wrA/2/

Comment: I'm using the CSS workaround `height:40px;` in the prodution code too ;), but the question is: why does this happens? I guess, setting the global attribute `display:block` in the CSS for every image is not right as the layout of some pages will be broken.

Comment: I think it's a bug - there are other posts around with the same issue.

Comment: I think it's not a bug - see my suggested answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to fix this problem correctly without height hacks, etc. is to set the container to line-height:0; (see demo example below).

```css
.image { background:red; }
.image-fix { line-height:0; }
```

```html
Image without Fix: 
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
</div>

<br>

Image with Fix: 
<div class="image image-fix">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a issue , you just need to write a correct CSS. Try

> height:40px;display:block; for div tag and keep margin:0,padding:0 
>   Thats all...

Comment: Read my answer regarding the rendering of image as an inline element.